# Why when i try to send heart rate values to real time database the sensor stops working arduino

Tags: c++, arduino, nodemcu, circuit

I'm using NodeMCU and max30100 sensor module, everything works fine in the code until I add this line to loop()

```
      if (Firebase.ready() && (millis() - sendDataPrevMillis > 15000 || sendDataPrevMillis == 0))
  {
    
    sendDataPrevMillis = millis();
    Firebase.setFloat(fbdo, "/test/heartrate", pox.getHeartRate());

}
```

Here is my full code

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include "MAX30100_PulseOximeter.h"
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include "Wire.h"
#include "Adafruit_GFX.h"
#include "OakOLED.h"
 
#define REPORTING_PERIOD_MS 1000
OakOLED oled;
 
// Connections : SCL PIN - D1 , SDA PIN - D2 , INT PIN - D0
PulseOximeter pox;
 #define WIFI_SSID "ZainFiber-2.4G-jAMj"
#define WIFI_PASSWORD "0796169690"
float BPM, SpO2;
uint32_t tsLastReport = 0;
 
const unsigned char bitmap [] PROGMEM=
{
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x80, 0x18, 0x00, 0x0f, 0xe0, 0x7f, 0x00, 0x3f, 0xf9, 0xff, 0xc0,
0x7f, 0xf9, 0xff, 0xc0, 0x7f, 0xff, 0xff, 0xe0, 0x7f, 0xff, 0xff, 0xe0, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xf0,
0xff, 0xf7, 0xff, 0xf0, 0xff, 0xe7, 0xff, 0xf0, 0xff, 0xe7, 0xff, 0xf0, 0x7f, 0xdb, 0xff, 0xe0,
0x7f, 0x9b, 0xff, 0xe0, 0x00, 0x3b, 0xc0, 0x00, 0x3f, 0xf9, 0x9f, 0xc0, 0x3f, 0xfd, 0xbf, 0xc0,
0x1f, 0xfd, 0xbf, 0x80, 0x0f, 0xfd, 0x7f, 0x00, 0x07, 0xfe, 0x7e, 0x00, 0x03, 0xfe, 0xfc, 0x00,
0x01, 0xff, 0xf8, 0x00, 0x00, 0xff, 0xf0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x7f, 0xe0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x3f, 0xc0, 0x00,
0x00, 0x0f, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x06, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
};
 
void onBeatDetected()
{
    Serial.println("Beat Detected!");
    oled.drawBitmap( 60, 20, bitmap, 28, 28, 1);
    oled.display();
}
 
void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASSWORD);
  Serial.print("Connecting to Wi-Fi");
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
  {
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(300);
  }
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connected with IP: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
    oled.begin();
    oled.clearDisplay();
    oled.setTextSize(1);
    oled.setTextColor(1);
    oled.setCursor(0, 0);
 
    oled.println("Initializing pulse oximeter..");
    oled.display();
    
    pinMode(16, OUTPUT);
 
    Serial.print("Initializing Pulse Oximeter..");
 
    if (!pox.begin())
    {
         Serial.println("FAILED");
         oled.clearDisplay();
         oled.setTextSize(1);
         oled.setTextColor(1);
         oled.setCursor(0, 0);
         oled.println("FAILED");
         oled.display();
         for(;;);
    }
    else
    {
         oled.clearDisplay();
         oled.setTextSize(1);
         oled.setTextColor(1);
         oled.setCursor(0, 0);
         oled.println("SUCCESS");
         oled.display();
         Serial.println("SUCCESS");
         pox.setOnBeatDetectedCallback(onBeatDetected);
    }
 
    // The default current for the IR LED is 50mA and it could be changed by uncommenting the following line.
     //pox.setIRLedCurrent(MAX30100_LED_CURR_7_6MA);
 
}
 
void loop()
{
    pox.update();
 
    BPM = pox.getHeartRate();
    SpO2 = pox.getSpO2();
     if (millis() - tsLastReport > REPORTING_PERIOD_MS)
    {
        Serial.print("Heart rate:");
        Serial.print(BPM);
        Serial.print(" bpm / SpO2:");
        Serial.print(SpO2);
        Serial.println(" %");
 
      
        
        oled.clearDisplay();
        oled.setTextSize(1);
        oled.setTextColor(1);
        oled.setCursor(0,16);
        oled.println(pox.getHeartRate());
 
        oled.setTextSize(1);
        oled.setTextColor(1);
        oled.setCursor(0, 0);
        oled.println("Heart BPM");
 
        oled.setTextSize(1);
        oled.setTextColor(1);
        oled.setCursor(0, 30);
        oled.println("Spo2");
 
        oled.setTextSize(1);
        oled.setTextColor(1);
        oled.setCursor(0,45);
        oled.println(pox.getSpO2());
        oled.display();
 
        tsLastReport = millis();
    }
}
```

Everything works fine until I add the above line to loop the sensor works but it only gives zero heart rate and spo2 and the lcd display also works but it only displays zero.
here is my circuit
[image]

Comment: There are a number of statements in those three lines of code. Can you pin-point _which_ statement causes the issue (`Firebase.ready()`, `pox.getHeartRate()`). Find a Minimal, Reproducible Example  and work with that: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Firebase.setFloat(fbdo, "/test/heartrate", pox.getHeartRate());
This statement when i added the sensor only gives zero readings

Comment: Then remove everything from the sketch apart from the interaction with the sensor; no Firefbase, no display. You first need correct readings before you can persist and/or display those.

Comment: When I remove that line only everything works fine, but when I added back it stops working.

Comment: Have you set your *Firebase host,* and what code do you use to set up the Firebase object?

Answer (score 0):

Looking it some [example code](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp8266-nodemcu-firebase-realtime-database/) it seems you aren't initializing Firebase properly:

```
//Define Firebase Data object
FirebaseData fbdo;
FirebaseAuth auth;
FirebaseConfig config;

void setup() {

    // WIFI setup goes here

    /* Assign the api key (required) */
    config.api_key = API_KEY;

    /* Assign the RTDB URL (required) */
    config.database_url = DATABASE_URL;

    /* Sign up */
    if (Firebase.signUp(&config, &auth, "", "")) {
        // is OK
    } else {
        // handle error
    }

    /* Assign the callback function for the long running token generation task */
    config.token_status_callback = tokenStatusCallback; //see addons/TokenHelper.h

    Firebase.begin(&config, &auth);
    Firebase.reconnectWiFi(true);
}
```